# Elements of the Galois Group of the splitting field of $x^3-5$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

So as in the title, I am trying to find what the elements of the Galois Group are. First of all we do the extension $Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$ which is of degree 3 using the polynomial $x^3-5$. Now we extend again to get $Q(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5})=E$ which is an extension of degree two. Hence we know that $|Gal(E/Q)|=6$. Now i want to find the elements of this group by looking at the automorphisms. We know we have to map $\sqrt[3]{5}$ to the other zeroes of $x^3-5$ and then map $\omega\sqrt[3]{5}$ to $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}$ or itself. However, we already know where the root of 5 maps so all we consider is where $\omega$ maps to. This is sort of obvious simply because $Q(\sqrt[3]{5},\omega\sqrt[3]{5})=Q(\omega,\sqrt[3]{5})$. However, i am having trouble finding a polynomial in $Q(\sqrt[3]{5})$ whose zeroes are $\omega$ and $\omega^2$. How do I find such a polynomial? Is it cyclotomic?

Comment: How about $(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)?$

Answer (score 1):

The automorphisms are induced by all permutations of $\sqrt[3]{5}$, $\omega\sqrt[3]{5}$, and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}$.  It seems like you want to know where each of these permutations takes $\omega$.  Well, the 3-cycles leave it alone since they have fixed field $\Bbb{Q}(\omega)$ by the Galois correspondence. (Or you can note that $\omega=\omega\sqrt[3]{5}/\sqrt[3]{5}$ will be taken to, say, $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}/\omega\sqrt[3]{5}=\omega$ by $\sqrt[3]{5}\rightarrow\omega\sqrt[3]{5}\rightarrow\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5}$.)

And the transpositions take $\omega$ to $\omega^2$, because half of the elements need to swap $\omega$ with its conjugate $\omega^2$ (or by looking, e.g., at what $\sqrt[3]{5}\rightarrow\omega\sqrt[3]{5}\rightarrow\sqrt[3]{5}$ does to $\omega=\omega\sqrt[3]{5}/\sqrt[3]{5}$).

Comment: One of the things that has often frustrated me about elementary problems like this in Galois theory is that there always seems to be some need of the "inside baseball," i.e. knowledge of solving similar problems previously, to make the key observations. I'm wondering if you could break down your reasoning into a sort of algorithm for answering OP's question in some level of generality?

Comment: If, as in this problem, you already know which permutations of the roots are in the Galois group, you can always write other field elements as  expressions involving those roots and elements of the ground field and then apply elements of the Galois group simply by applying the corresponding permutations of the roots.  This is why I gave those explicit computations as an alternate solution.